# jquery append html elements - passing javascript variable as class

Tags: jquery

I have got the following jquery code which appends some html elements to the `<a>` tag found inside a `<li>` tag.

Currently, i am hardcoding the class of the `<ins>` tag, but actually i need to pass a javascript variable (selected_class) as the the class name.

```
 if (colour[1] == "blue"){
  selected_class = "colour-icon1";
  }
  else if (colour[1] == "yellow")  {
   selected_class = "colour-icon2";
  }
  else if (colour[1] == "green")  {
   selected_class = "colour-icon3";
  }


      $j("li[name='"+node_name+"'] > a").append('<a><ins class="colour-icon1">&nbsp;</ins></a>');
```

My question is how do i pass a javascript variable (selected_class) as the the class name inside the `<ins>` tag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$j("li[name='"+node_name+"'] > a").append('<a><ins class="' + selected_class + '">&nbsp;</ins></a>');
```

Should do the trick. You're already doing string concatenation in your selector:

```
li[name='"+node_name+"']
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var selected_class = ...;
var ins = $j("<ins>").addClass(selected_class);
var newLink = $j("<a>").append(ins).append("&nbsp;");
$j("li[name='" + node_name + "'] > a").append(newLink);
```

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at [jQuery.addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/). I believe it's what you're looking for.

I'm not adept at creating selectors yet so I can't help there. Though it seems [Phil Klein](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8564813/63609) has a solution for you.